# AWS Route 53 - Domain name route to different ports of an Application load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

We are implementing a micro-services architecture in AWS. We have several EC2 instances which has the micro-services deployed on different ports. We also have an internet facing Application Load Balancer, which routes to different services based on the port.

```
eg: 
xxxx-xx.xx.elb.amazonaws.com:8080/ go to microservice 1 
xxxx-xx.xx.elb.amazonaws.com:8090/ go to microservice 2
```

We need to have a domain name instead of the ELB, the port should not be exposed through the domain name as well. Almost all the resources I found regarding route 53, use alias which does the following:

```
xx.xxxx.co.id -> xxxx-xx.xx.elb.amazonaws.com or
xx.xxxx.co.id -> 111.111.111.11 (static ip)
```

1) Do we need separate domains for each micro service?

2) How to use alias to point domains to a specific port of the ELB?

3) Is it possible to use this setup if the domains are from another provider other than AWS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Important Update**

Since this answer was originally written, Application Load Balancer [introduced the capability for ALB to route requests to a specific target group based on the `Host` header of the incoming request](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/).

The incoming host header can now be used to route requests to specific instances and ports.

Additionally, [ALB introduced SNI support](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-sni/), allowing you to associate multiple TLS (SSL) certificates with a single balancer, and the correct certificate will be automatically selected based on the SNI presented by the client when TLS is negotiated.  Multi-domain and wildcard certs from Amazon Certificate Manager also work with ALB.

Based on these factors, no separate ports or different listeners are needed -- simply assign hostnames and/or path prefixes for each service, and map those patterns to the appropriate target group of instances.

The original answer is no longer accurate, but is included below.

---

> 1.) Do we need separate domains for each micro service?

No, this won't help you.  ALB does not interpret the hostname attached to the incoming request.

Separate hostnames in the same domain won't directly accomplish your objective, either.

> 2.) How to use alias to point domains to a specific port of the ELB?

Domains do not point to ports. Hostnames do not point to ports. DNS is only used for address resolution.  This is true everywhere on the Internet.

> 3.) Is it possible to use this setup if the domains are from another provider other than AWS.

This is not a limitation of AWS.  DNS simply does not work this way.

A service endpoint is unaware of the DNS records that point to it.  The DNS entry itself is strictly used for discovering an IP address that can be used to access the endpoint.  After that, the endpoint does not actually know anything about the DNS, and there is no way to tell the browser, via DNS, to use a different port.

For HTTP, the implicit port is 80.  For HTTPS, it is 443.  Unless a port is provided in the URL, these are the *only* usable ports.

However, in HTTP and HTTPS, each request is accompanied by a `Host:` header, sent by the web browser with each request.  This is the hostname in the address bar.

To differentiate between requests for different hostnames arriving at a device (such as ELB/ALB), the device at the endpoint must interpret the incoming host header and route the request to an back-end system providing that service.

ALB does not currently support this capability.

ALB does, however, support choosing endpoints based on a path prefix.  So microservices.example.com/api/foo could route to one set of services, while microservices.example.com/api/bar could route to another.

But ALB does not directly support routing by host header.

---

In my infrastructure, we use a combination of ELB or ALB, but the instances behind the load balancer are **not** the applications.  Instead, they are instances that run HAProxy load balancer software, and route the requests to the backend.

A brief example of the important configuration elements looks like this:

```
frontend main
  use_backend svc1 if { hdr(Host) -i foo.example.com }
  use_backend svc2 if { hdr(Host) -i bar.example.com }

backend svc1
  server foo-a 192.168.2.24:8080
  server foo-b 192.168.12.18:8080

backend svc2
  ....
```

The ELB terminates the SSL and selects a proxy at random and the proxy checks the `Host:` header and selects a backend (a group of 1 or more instances) to which the request will be routed.  It is a thin layer between the ELB and the application, which handles the request routing by examining the host header or any other characteristic of the request.

This is one solution, but is a somewhat advanced configuration, depending on your expertise.

---

If you are looking for an out-of-the-box, serverless, AWS-centric solution, then the answer is actually found in CloudFront.  Yes, it's a CDN, but it has several other applications, including as a reverse proxy.

- For each service, choose a hostname from your domain to assign to that service, foo.api.example.com or bar.api.example.com.
- For each service, create a CloudFront distribution.
- Configure the Alternate Domain Name of each distribution to use that service's assigned hostname.
- Set the Origin Domain Name to the ELB hostname.
- Set the [Origin HTTP Port](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesHTTPPort) to the service's specific port on the ALB, e.g. 8090.
- Configure the default Cache Behavior to forward any headers you need.  If you don't need the caching capability of CloudFront, choose Forward All Headers.  Also enable forwarding of Query Strings and Cookies if needed.
- In Route 53, create foo.api.example.com as an Alias to that specific CloudFront distribution's hostname, e.g. dxxxexample.cloudfront.net.

Your problem is solved.

You see what I did there?

For each hostname you configure, a dedicated CloudFront distribution receives the request on the standard ports (80/443) and -- based on which distribution the host header matches -- CloudFront routes the requests to the **same** ELB/ALB hostname but a **custom** port number.

Comment: Thank you. That is a really good explanation. Unfortunately we wont be able to move on with the CloudFront because we already have the microservices setup with the elb. And its currently in testing stage. So we will have to go with the other solution that you mentioned. I am new to AWS infrastructure, would you be able to point me in the correct direction with HAProxy

Comment: I'm not sure I was clear, or that you have fully understood my answer, based on your comment that *"we already have the microservices setup with the elb."*  The ELB remains in place, unchanged.  CloudFront can allow you to point multiple hostnames at the different ports of the ELB without needing ports in the URLs.  This should be a much less disruptive change compared to using HAProxy.

Comment: I was under the impression that we have to do over using Cloudfront. Thank you for clarifying that for me. I am new for AWS so i really appreciate your comment. I will look into cloudfront. Can you give any pointers for that if it not a problem for you.

Comment: Take a look at the steps in the bulleted list, above.  You should be able to walk through these in CloudFront and Route 53 without changing anything about your current setup -- this becomes what I'll call an "overlay" -- it's an "alternate" way of accessing your services, and it won't stop them from working the way they already work, now. Once you have this working, the old way (`http://elb-host:8090`) will technically still work, you just won't need to use it.  Also, click my name to see my profile if you need my contact information.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a possibility that he can build what he's describing. I was in the same boat for a while, here's some options for you to consider:

- In R53 create a hosted zone - and point your domain at it.
- Optional step: create ALIAS records. You can do this for each subdomain or
  app. Leave the ALIAS field blank if using the root domain.
- Create a record set using the SLA option, which is a service lookup for port
  redirection. Try to point this to your LB port 80, alias the sub-domains.
- Change your load balancer's listeners, to listen on port 80 - then redirect app traffic based on your apps port settings.

I havent used SLA, but this would definitely point you in that direction.