# Path-based routing to external resource with AWS Application Load-Balancer (ALB)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, devops, elastic-load-balancer

I have a working domain, x.y, which is tied to an EC2 instance on a VPC.

I want a path on that domain, x.y/z, to be routed to an external, non-AWS (IPv4*) microservice. Can this be done with ALB?

I have followed [Use Path-Based Routing with Your Application Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html) to set up target groups, but can't seem to link them to anything past EC2 instances?

(*: Would be great to extend with ports, or even (sub)domains, paths, etc.)

Comment: You can only route to AWS target groups (EC2 instances).

Comment: Different question but similar solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41828037/1695906).  CloudFront in front of ALB can route requests to different endpoints (including ports) both inside and outside of AWS, integrating multiple services behind a single hostname.  Or, HAProxy in EC2 behind ALB can forward to external targets.

Comment: It seems past(old) instance present outside VPC of target Groups so why this instance is not linking with alb using path-based-routing .

Answer (score 4):

The latest AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB) can do the trick. This works for me

**Follow the steps here,**

**1. Set up the ALB** 
 AWS documentation here, Follow steps up until Listeners tab,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html

**2. On the Listeners tab,**
**2.1. Modify rules in the Listeners ID**

[image]

**2.2. Add Rule:**
[image]

**2.3. Point to redirect URL**
[image]

This should redirect you to external URL

Comment: I think the original goal was to forward the request to a non-AWS host and not redirect the end-user to a different domain name.

Answer (score 0):

I also have similar requirement. I want to forward request to external AWS TargetGroup to save ConnectionTime and DNS Resolution time. Both the Account infra are within my company network so it will be possible to forward path based request from one aws ALB to another AWS api. I tried to create rule to forward request, there it is asking to select TG which is listing only TGs belong to current VPC. Not sure how can i point to TG of another AWS account.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlDKx.png)