# Which is the best way to route paths on AWS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, path, routes

My name is Diego and this is my first question on the site. I'm Argentinian, so, sorry for my bad english.

I was introduced into Amazon Web Services (AWS) four months ago, and I worked with services like EC2, S3, Route53, IAM, etc.

Now, I have the next scenario:

- An EC2 (1), with a website based on React (frontend) and Node.js (backend)
- An EC2 (2), with a webapp based on React Native and Express.js

In Route53 I registered the **domain.com** pointed to the first EC2 (the website, on **port 80**), and the webapp is running on the second EC2, on **port 3000**.

After searching and read a lot a few days (I will let the links at the end of the post) I came here to solve the doubt.

**The question is the following:**

When I go to **domain.com**, I will come on the website, so, some paths like **/home, /services, /ourworks, /team, etc.**  will be part of it. But... If the word that comes after the bar isn't it one of this, I need to send the user to the second EC2 on **port 3000**, that is to say, the **webapp**. After that, the webapp will know what to do with the route.

So...

**What is the best way to route this scenario?**

I have read about:

-Use an **.htaccess** to routing paths and ports. This was fine in the last scenario, when the website was a Wordpress site, but now the website is based on React and Nodejs, so, we not use Apache anymore, so this solution is useless for me.

-Use the routing of the **Application Load Balancer** (ALB). This is fine, but the price of this service is so expensive, so I can't use this by now.

-Use the routing of the **API Gateway** service, but after read a lot, I can't find an official documentation of how to route with API Gateway to an EC2 server directly. All of the documentation speak about APIs REST or APIs with WebSockets, with DynamoDB or Lambda service. None of that is useful for me. I can't understand how to use API Gateway for my purpouse.

-Use **NGINX** on the EC2 which **domain.com** points, and route paths from this point. this's maybe a good solution, but I never worked with this software.

So, i'm so confused right now. **Can anybody tell me which is the best solution for my problem, and why?** I will really appreciate that.

---

The links I have read these days:

-[Redirecting with htaccess to nodejs app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386994/redirecting-with-htaccess-to-nodejs-app) (I don't know if using Apache is a good solution)

-https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/71lz5v/applications_routing_based_on_url/ (This is a good post on Reddit)

-https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/ (Use ALB and spend a lot of money, haha)

-[AWS Route 53 - Domain name route to different ports of an Application load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821505/aws-route-53-domain-name-route-to-different-ports-of-an-application-load-balan/41828037#41828037) (More of ALB, but this is so interesting)

-https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=152643 (This is the scenario most similar to mine, but poor man, never got answer)

Well, thanks to all for read and, if I violated any rule on the forum, please forgive me. Goodbye! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

greetings from Colombia =)

My best advice here is to put Nginx upfront on those EC2 instances and use it as a proxy or load balancer, the best approach would be the one where you could even run multiple processes of your apps in the same EC2 instance providing a better scalability and balance the load using Nginx, here are two articles to accomplish this setup:

https://nodesource.com/blog/running-your-node-js-app-with-systemd-part-1/
https://nodesource.com/blog/running-your-node-js-app-with-systemd-part-2/

There are other options with more complex approaches as the ones you are describing, but I think this one is the simplest and cheapest.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I will be reading those posts this night. Meanwhile, i have only one question: why u say to put **two** instances of NGINX? One in each EC2? I think one instance of NGINX in the first EC2 is enough to route all. Or maybe u said that because think of NGINX like a Load Balancer for the two apps?

Comment: Exactly, my idea is to launch multiple processes for the apps and then make NGINX balance the load between all processes running